# C++ code failing to compile when defining a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

My code is failing to compile and I am getting these error messages. I've looked at similar questions but nothing seemed quite right. I don't understand what is causing the problem as I've declared my function and defined it below main.

```
declaration is incompatible with "void reprchar(char ch, int n)" (declared at line 18)C/C++(147) [4,6]
variable or field 'reprchar' declared void gcc [4,14]
'reprchar' was not declared in this scope gcc [7,5]
expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type C/C++(109) [7,5]
expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type C/C++(109) [9,5]
expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type C/C++(109) [14,5]
declaration is incompatible with "void reprchar" (declared at line 4) C/C++(147) [18,6]
```

The code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void reprchar('a', 54);

int main() {
    reprchar('*', 45);
    cout << "Data type      Range" << endl;
    reprchar('-', 23);
    cout << "char       -128 to 127" << endl
         << "short      -32,768 to 32,767" << endl
         << "int        System Dependent" << endl
         << "double     -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647" << endl;
    reprchar('*', 45);
    return 0;
}

void reprchar(char ch, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << ch;
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This void reprchar('a', 54); is not a function declaration. You need to declare parameters instead of using expressions.

Comment: You just need `void reprchar(char, int);` for a declaration. What you have right now instead is a function call.

Comment: @Zoso `void reprchar('char, int);` will not work

Comment: `void reprchar('a', 54);` Half declaration. Half invocation. All non-compilable.

Comment: @0___________ The offending quote mark?

Comment: Side note: In addition to fixing the function declaration, you could eliminate the need for the declaration by moving the function definition to before its first usage.

Comment: Thanks the book I'm following has a typo then

Answer (score 1):

`void reprchar('a', 54);` is invalid

replace with the correct prototype

```
void reprchar(char, int);
```

Comment: Ah thanks the book I'm following has a typo then

Comment: @adamacc123 change the book